# Как правильно хранить токен и для чего нужен презентер?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, dagger2, moxy

Использую даггер2 и MOXY(mvp). У даггера есть модуль, в котором осуществляются  создание ретрофит билдера и в нем осуществляются http запросы. В презентере я отлавливаю колбеки. И один из колбеков осуществляет получение accesstoken'а. Интерсептор написать не могу, так как у меня несколько сервисов для отправки http запросов с разным базовым урлом. Что делать в моем случае? Где хранить токен?

Answer (score 0):

Не в курсе что есть MOXY, но презентер не должен колбеки отлавливать, он должен получать уже готовый результат. Не знаю что такое интерсепторы, но можно сделать столько компонентов (в терминологии дагера) сколько фантазия позволяет (сколько разных урлов).

Задача презентера передать действия/команды пользователя бизнес-логике и отобразить результат пользователю (в виде обновления содержимого интерфейса, ошибки, переход на другой экран и т.п).

Токен нужно хранить так (и где), чтобы его было удобно использовать в дальнейшем